# How Can I add Links in column of WIX table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, velo

I am implementing crypto API. Latest news and the current market cap on the Wix platform.

**I am using table format I have done with all the things like images, text, and dates are shown in the columns but, I need one more thing that is the link through which user can be able to click on it and go to the original news.**

Here is my code for the showing news with WIX library `$w`.

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(function () {
//TODO: write your page related code here...
fetch("https://data.messari.io/api/v1/news", {method: "get"})
.then( (httpResponse) => {
let url = httpResponse.url;
let statusCode = httpResponse.status;
let statusText = httpResponse.statusText;
let headers = httpResponse.headers;
let bodyUsed = httpResponse.bodyUsed;
if (httpResponse.ok) {
return httpResponse.json();
}
else {
return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
}
} )
.then( (json) => {
// $w('#text21').post;
// const myTableData = [
// {"name": "A", "age": 45},
// {"name": "B", "age": 34},
// {"name": "C", "num": 19}
// ];
var mydata = json.data;
for(let i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++){
delete mydata[i].id;
delete mydata[i].author;
delete mydata[i].references;
delete mydata[i].tags;

}
console.log(mydata);

$w("#table1").rows = mydata;
// console.log(json.data);
// console.log(mydata);
} )
.catch( (err) => {
console.log(err);
} );
```

in the JSON variable I have got the news link But, When I modify it and concatenate with

`mydata.push({'link': json.data[i].link});` // Push the link in the mydata variable so that I can send to table in the for loop.

```
mydata[i].link = "<a href="+mydata[i].link+">Click Here</a>"; // edting for render a link tag in for loop too.
```

**Issue is that it shows the table full anchor tag, not like `click here`**

I am not able to find out the solution for that if you know please post the answer for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the data type Rich Text for the column. The data type can be chosen from the mange Column for the data table. The Rich text will help you to show your HTML content as you want.